# Replacing red threes

Tags: canasta

If a player is dealt (i.e., dealt during the deal, not as draws drawn later) red threes and on their first turn they want to pick up the pile, when do they pick up the replacement cards for the red threes?

Comment: What do you mean if they are dealt three red 3's?

Comment: Not quite sure what's unclear about this question... it's simply asking when to draw the replacements for red threes that you are dealt in the initial deal.

Comment: @GendoIkari When it says dealt 3 red threes I see that as either being in the players hand or it could be that they are the cards being drawn from the top of the deck when playing a turn.

Comment: @JoeW "is dealt" doesn't need to be clarified to disambiguate it from "draws"; it already doesn't mean "draws".

Comment: @GendoIkari I disagree with that statement and if you think it is so clear you could edit the question to fix my confusion.

Comment: I can't see anything in this question to be confused about.

Answer (score 6):

If you are dealt red 3s, you place them in front of you and draw replacements before the hand even begins; before it would be your first turn.

> The Deal
>
> > Each player must immediately place face-up in front of them any red threes they were dealt, and draw an equal number of cards from the top of the face-down pile to replace them.

https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#classic-threes